# Siri Shortcuts: Update contact info?

Tags: sirishortcuts

Using the new Siri Shortcuts, is it possible to create a shortcut to update the street address of an existing contact, with your current location? I can't find anything that will let me do that...

Cheers,
Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, as of October 2018, is no: There is no way to change the contents of Contacts by using the Shortcuts -app.

Comment: I thought that would be the case. Shame!

Comment: @user3514446 i have a great deal of hope that Apple will address these issues. As development on Shortcuts is on-going (they have a Beta out for version 2.1 now)